# JQuery preventdefault not working in code

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I am using fancy box plugin to play video in lightbox. The video plays correctly with the current code but as the hash is used in href, the page always goes to top. I have tried using preventDefault() but no use.

I tried searching in different answers related to preventdefault but no use.

This is my code below. Please Help

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(".fancy_video").prepend("<span class=\"playbutton\"/>")

  // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT
  jQuery(".fancy_video").fancybox({
    scrolling: "no",
    padding: 0,
    nextEffect: "fade",
    prevEffect: "fade",
    nextSpeed: 0,
    prevSpeed: 0,
    fitToView: true,
    autoSize: true,
    modal: false, // hide default close and navigation buttons
    helpers: {
      media: {}
    }
  });

  $('#video1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#data1").find('video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    $('#video_size').get(0).play();
  })

  $('#video2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#data2").find('video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    $('#video_size1').get(0).play();
  })

  $('#video3').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#data3").find('video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    $('#video_size2').get(0).play();
  })

  $('#video4').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#data4").find('video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    $('#video_size3').get(0).play();
  })

  $('#video5').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#data5").find('video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    $('#video_size4').get(0).play();
  })

  $('#video6').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#data6").find('video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    $('#video_size5').get(0).play();
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="http://mediasphereindia.com/apac/pages/mobile_video/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="video">
  <figure>
    <a class="fancy_video" href="#data5" id="video5">
      <img class="videoThumb" src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-inline.png">
    </a>
    <div style="display:none">
      <div style="display:inline;" id="data5">
        <video id="video_size4" preload="none" controls>
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-inline.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-inline.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-inline.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

          <object width="100%" height="90%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;file=/apac/images/videos/mobile_video/inview-inline.mp4" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
          </object>

        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <h3 class="videoTitle">InView Inline</h3>
  <p>Video ad auto-plays inline with content without sound as it appears on screen and pauses if people scroll past. Clicking on the video takes you to the advertiser landing page.</p>
</article>

<article class="video">
  <figure>
    <a class="fancy_video" href="#data6" id="video6">
      <img class="videoThumb" src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-pushdown.png">
    </a>
    <div style="display:none">
      <div style="display:inline;" id="data6">
        <video id="video_size5" preload="none" controls>
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-pushdown.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-pushdown.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/inview-pushdown.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

          <object width="100%" height="90%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;file=/apac/images/videos/mobile_video/inview-pushdown.mp4" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
          </object>

        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <h3 class="videoTitle">InView Pushdown</h3>
  <p>Video ad auto-plays by pushing the page half down. Video pauses if people scroll past. Clicking on the video takes you to the advertiser landing page.</p>
</article>


<article class="video">
  <figure>
    <a class="fancy_video" href="#data1" id="video1">
      <img class="videoThumb" src="images/videos/mobile_video/maxvdo.png">
    </a>
    <div style="display:none">
      <div style="display:inline;" id="data1">
        <video id="video_size" preload="none" controls>
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/maxvdo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/maxvdo.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/maxvdo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

          <object width="100%" height="90%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;file=/apac/images/videos/mobile_video/maxvdo.mp4" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
          </object>

        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <h3 class="videoTitle">Max.VDO</h3>
  <p>With a total unit size of 320px x 288px, this format allows the unit to push down the entire screen. Auto-plays video ads and resolves to original app or mobile site.</p>
</article>




<article class="video">
  <figure>
    <a class="fancy_video" id="video3" href="#data3">
      <img class="videoThumb" src="images/videos/mobile_video/minivdo.png">
    </a>
    <div style="display:none">
      <div style="display:inline;" id="data3">
        <video id="video_size2" preload="none" controls>
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/minivdo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/minivdo.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/minivdo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

          <object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;=true&amp;file=/apac/images/videos/mobile_video/minivdo.mp4" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />

          </object>

        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <h3 class="videoTitle">Mini.VDO</h3>
  <p>Mini.VDO offers an expanding panel that plays within the horizontal banner on the top of the screen. Compatible with all devices across Mobile Web, delivering exceptional quality.</p>
</article>


<article class="video">
  <figure>
    <a class="fancy_video" id="video4" href="#data4">
      <img class="videoThumb" src="images/videos/mobile_video/prerollvdo.png">
    </a>
    <div style="display:none">
      <div style="display:inline;" id="data4">
        <video id="video_size3" preload="none" controls>
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/prerollvdo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/prerollvdo.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="images/videos/mobile_video/prerollvdo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

          <object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="/apac/pages/adgallery/scripts/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;=true&amp;file=/apac/images/videos/mobile_video/prerollvdo.mp4" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />

          </object>

        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <h3 class="videoTitle">PreRoll</h3>
  <p>This 320px x 480px ad space can change based on different integrations. Ad units can play within site pages, or within native video player across Mobile Web and Apps. The unit supports an ad space of 480px x 270px for horizontal orientation in iPhone.</p>
</article>
```

I am sorry i tried the code again and the line where i am using preventDefault() is of no use. Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding dynamically then need to fire this way for appending event listeners to dynamic content is as follows

$(document).on( event, selector, callback );